# Object Reference not set when using PrinterSettings.StringCollection

Tags: c#, object, reference

I am attempting to list the currently installed printers using `PrinterSettings.StringCollection`. However, I get this error:

> Object Reference not set to an instance of an object

Code is as follows:

```
namespace DropDownLibrary
{
    public class DropDownExample : DSDropDownBase
    {
        public DropDownExample() : base("item") { }

        public static PrinterSettings.StringCollection InstalledPrinters { get; }

        public override void PopulateItems()
        {
            // The Items collection contains the elements
            // that appear in the list.            

            Items.Clear();

            // Create a number of DynamoDropDownItem objects 
            // to store the items that we want to appear in our list.

            var newItems = new List<DynamoDropDownItem>();
            {
                 foreach (String name in InstalledPrinters)
                 {
                     new DynamoDropDownItem("{0}", name);
                 }
            };

            Items.AddRange(newItems);

            // Set the selected index to something other
            // than -1, the default, so that your list
            // has a pre-selection.

            SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        public override IEnumerable<AssociativeNode> BuildOutputAst(List<AssociativeNode> inputAstNodes)
        {
            // Build an AST node for the type of object contained in your Items collection.

            var intNode = AstFactory.BuildIntNode((int)Items[SelectedIndex].Item);
            var assign = AstFactory.BuildAssignment(GetAstIdentifierForOutputIndex(0), intNode);

            return new List<AssociativeNode> { assign };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't assign a value to InstalledPrinters anywhere.

Comment: I'm real new to C# , isn't "public static PrinterSettings.StringCollection InstalledPrinters { get; }" assigning the stringcollection to installedprinters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). The 'Object reference not set to instance of an Object" error is caused by you trying to use a variable that is null. For instance, you can get a null reference error by doing:

```
object nullObject = null;
nullObject.ToString():
```

In your code, it doesn't look like the value for `InstalledPrinters` ever gets set.

Before your code reaches this line:

```
foreach (String name in InstalledPrinters)
```

It looks like you copy pasted this from [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.installedprinters):

```
public static PrinterSettings.StringCollection InstalledPrinters { get; }
```

This is a property on the PrinterSettings class that you can access. You should access it like so:

```
var installedPrinters = System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters;

foreach (String name in installedPrinters)
```

Comment: Thanks jyanks. I understand the error I just can't figure out how it's happening. Thanks for the help!

Comment: See the code I just updated. You need to instantiate InstalledPrinters. Where do you think the list of installed printers is coming from?

Comment: I get the error "there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'array'   of PrinterSettings.StringCollection.StringCollection(string[])" when adding in your line. I thought I could access the installed printers on my system using System.Drawing.Printing..

Comment: Ah. So if you're looking at [this code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.installedprinters) which looks like is what you've copy pasted, you should actually reference it via `System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters`. I don't know if you can do that from an asp.net app, but I'll update my answer assuming it is possible.

Comment: Yeh exactly, although I did adjust my code based on your answer. I removed  "public static PrinterSettings.StringCollection InstalledPrinters { get; }" and added     System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters in the foreach line.... I now get the error : Index was out of range, parameter: Index which I think is due to the compatibility as you say...

Comment: I'm guessing that that's the cause. The System.Drawing.Printing is a Win32 library.

Comment: mm that's annoying, thanks for your help though mate, good to know I'm not going mental trying to get it to work

Comment: this might be a very beginner question jyanks but how can you tell the code is from an asp.net app?

Comment: `DSDropDownBase` is an asp.net class used for drawing the dropdowns, I thought.

Comment: I see, when I go to the definition it appears as:namespace DSCoreNodesUI
{
    public abstract class DSDropDownBase : NodeModel
    {
        protected DSDropDownBase();
        protected DSDropDownBase(string outputName);

        public ObservableCollection<DynamoDropDownItem> Items { get; set; }
        public int SelectedIndex { get; set; }

        public static int ParseSelectedIndex(string index, IList<DynamoDropDownItem> items);
        public static string SaveSelectedIndex(int index, IList<DynamoDropDownItem> items);

Comment: Sorry about the shoddy comment formatting, i'm still getting used to this site. And thanks for your help, i'm just trying to make sure for certain that I can't do what i'm trying to achieve

Comment: What kind of project did you choose when you started coding in visual studio?

Comment: I believe it is .NET Framework 4.5. Don't worry though mate, I managed to get it working and it's displaying all local and network printers which is just what I was after. Thanks for your help!